# How to retrieve Adaptive Card's form submission in subsequent waterfall step

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I'm using the Bot Framework (V4) and I've got a WaterfallDialog with two steps; first step is to capture form data and the second step is to process form data.

The first step sends a reply:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CaptureFormStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var reply = await stepContext.Context.Activity.GetReplyFromCardAsync("BusinessyForm");
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
}
```

The `GetReplyFromCardAsync` is an extension method which takes a JSON representation of an `Activity` with an adaptive card as an attachnent. The adaptive card is a form similiar to [this](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/Inputs.html). The adaptive card also has a submit action.

My question is how should this information be passed to the next step?

In previous attempts, I've returned a Prompt:

```
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
    "custom-prompt-id", 
    new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Hello!") }, 
    cancellationToken);
```

But in this context I do not want to prompt the user for additional info. Ideally, I'd like to "hold" the dialog state for a response and when one is detected the proceeding next step will process the submission result.

Things that I've tried:

- Reviewed examples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards/CardsBot.cs) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards/AdaptiveCardsBot.cs). Both shows how cards can be rendered but not how to handle input in subsequent steps.
- Reviewed card schema documentation for inputs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/card-schema).
- Reviewed discussion of similar issue in GitHub's AdaptiveCard repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/614).

Is this feasible? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adaptive Cards send their Submit results a little different than regular user text. When a user types in the chat and sends a normal message, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Text`. When a user fills out an input on an Adaptive Card, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Value`, which is an object where the key names are the `id` in your card and the values are the field values in the adaptive card.

For example, the json:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Test Adaptive Card"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Text:"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 20
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "userText",
                            "placeholder": "Enter Some Text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

.. creates a card that looks like:

[image: Test Adaptive Card]

If a user enters "Testing Testing 123" in the text box and hits Submit, `Context.Activity` will look something like:

```
{ type: 'message',
  value: { userText: 'Testing Testing 123' },
  from: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-05d4-478a-9daa-9b18c79bb66b', name: 'User' },
  locale: '',
  channelData: { postback: true },
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-be61-091ac0e3a4ac|livechat' },
  id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-ad8e-63b45e3ebfa7',
  localTimestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  timestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.773Z,
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58453' }
```

The user submission can be seen in `Context.Activity.Value.userText`.

Note that adaptive card submissions are sent as a postBack, which means that the submission data doesn't appear in the chat window as part of the conversation--it stays on the Adaptive Card.

**Using Adaptive Cards with [Waterfall Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#waterfall-dialogs)**

Natively, Adaptive Cards don't work like prompts. With a prompt, the prompt will display and wait for user input before continuing. But with Adaptive Cards (even if it contains an input box and a submit button), there is no code in an Adaptive Card that will cause a Waterfall Dialog to wait for user input before continuing the dialog.

So, if you're using an Adaptive Card that takes user input, you generally want to handle whatever the user submits outside of the context of a Waterfall Dialog.

That being said, if you want to use an Adaptive Card as part of a Waterfall Dialog, there is a workaround. Basically, you:

1. Display the Adaptive Card
2. Display a Text Prompt
3. Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt

In your Waterfall Dialog class (steps 1 and 2):

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayCardAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create the Adaptive Card
    var cardPath = Path.Combine(".", "AdaptiveCard.json");
    var cardJson = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
    var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardJson),
    };

    // Create the text prompt
    var opts = new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = new Activity
        {
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment },
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
            Text = "waiting for user input...", // You can comment this out if you don't want to display any text. Still works.
        }
    };

    // Display a Text Prompt and wait for input
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), opts);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleResponseAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Do something with step.result
    // Adaptive Card submissions are objects, so you likely need to JObject.Parse(step.result)
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
    return await stepContext.NextAsync();
}
```

In your main bot class (`<your-bot>.cs`), under `OnTurnAsync()`, near the beginning of the method, somewhere before `await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken)` is called (step 3):

```cs
var activity = turnContext.Activity;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
{
    activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, apologies for the delay. I'll be able to test this tomrrow and will update you then.

Comment: Perfect! It took a while as I mistakenly added your step 3 updates after my `await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken)` which skipped the step for handling the response.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I'll edit my answer to show better placement.

Comment: Thank you @mdrichardson. this aproach works for us. Hope there is an adaptive card prompt dialog added in future.

Comment: Update: there is now an official AdaptiveCardPrompt, however, I find that it still has the same issue of not waiting for the user selection/input/submit on the card before continuing.

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, I am using Bot Builder SDK v4.16.1 and supporting MSFT Teams as a primary channel, is this workaround required? OnTurnAsync is overridden in DialogBot<T> class where base.OnTurnAsync is called and saved any state changes that might have occurred during the turn. Is step3 needed here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is nodejs version:

your bot.ts file:

```
 this.onTurn(async (context, next) => {
  if (context.activity.type == ActivityTypes.Message) {
    // Ensure that message is a postBack (like a submission from Adaptive Cards)
    if (context.activity.channelData != null) {
      if (context.activity.channelData.postBack === true) {
        const postbackActivity = context.activity;
        // Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt
        // Must be sent as a string
        postbackActivity.text = JSON.stringify(postbackActivity.value);
        // context.activity.text = postbackActivity.value
        await context.sendActivity(postbackActivity);
      }
    }
  }
  await next();
});
```