# How to add a custom payload to PromptDialog.Choice

Tags: botframework

I am trying to add a custom data payload to PromptDialog.Choice / or PromptDialog.Text to indicate a special activity to my bot client.

I know there is a field to specify InputHint to IMessageActivity.
is there a way to add an inputhint/ or a custom tag to PromptDialog flow?

Comment: What version of the bot framework? Are you using node.js or c#?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use something like this:

```
var options = new PromptOptions()
{
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Pick Me!"),
    Choices = new List<Choice>()
};
var channelData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
channelData["testKey"] = "testValue";
options.Choices.Add(new Choice()
{
    // Value must be set. There's a PR in place to fix this, but for now just leave blank
    Value = "",
    Action = new CardAction()
    {
        // PostBack will prevent the user from seeing "Actual Value" after they select it
        Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
        Title = "DISPLAYED TEXT",
        Value = "ACTUAL VALUE",
    }
});
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), options);
```

The comments I left in the code should be explanatory enough.

Another solution might be to display a set of cards that include the `ChannelData`, then a blank text prompt to wait for the user's response. I have [a pretty in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066910/10860086) for how to do this. You'd just need to add a [`ChannelData` property](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/) so that you can capture your "special activity" code.

Comment: i don't see channelData object being used in your code snippet

Comment: When creating the `Activity`, you add the cards to `Activity.attachments`.  `Activity` also holds `ChannelData`, so while constructing your `Activity`, use something like `ChannelData = new { SpecialKey = SpecialValue }`