# I am using Bot framework V4.3, I want to retrieve adaptive card submit values

Tags: botframework

I'm using Bot framework V4.3, I have been using adaptive card in waterfall dialog, to get user information, I would want to get values once user clicks submit button and also I would like to go back to previous step if user click back button.

Here is how my adaptive card looks like

[image: Adaptive card]

I have tried the solution given by @mdrichardson in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061325/how-to-retrieve-adaptive-cards-form-submission-in-subsequent-waterfall-step) 
But the adaptive card re-prompts again.

And the below code help us to go back to previous step but how to implement it to back button of adaptive card.

```
stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] =(int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 2;
```

Adding adaptive card to dialog. *I had even used TextPrompt instead of ChoicePrompt*

```
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("AdaptiveCardPrompt") { Style = ListStyle.None });
```

This is how I'm displaying adaptive card. My adaptive card is in Json format

```
cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();

return await stepContext.PromptAsync("AdaptiveCardPrompt",
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = cardAttachment.Content
        }),
    }, cancellationToken);
```

Kindly help me in solving this issue. Thank you in advance

## Edit from Botframework Support: Please do not use the code block below. It only works in Emulator. Instead, use:

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
{
    activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
}
```

<strike>**Edit 1**:  @mdrichardson Here is how I have setup the dialog call</strike>

```
        public static async Task Run(this Dialog dialog, ITurnContext turnContext,IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> accessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
            dialogSet.Add(dialog);

            var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            // Ensure that message is a postBack (like a submission from Adaptive Cards)
            if (dialogContext.Context.Activity.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelData") != null)
            {
                var channelData = JObject.Parse(dialogContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                if (channelData.ContainsKey("postBack"))
                {
                    var postbackActivity = dialogContext.Context.Activity;
                    // Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt
                    // Must be sent as a string
                    postbackActivity.Text = postbackActivity.Value.ToString();
                    await dialogContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(postbackActivity);
                }
            }
            var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
            {
                await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

And in `OnTurnAsync` method

```
 if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
 {
      await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
 }
```

**Edit 2** : I modified the code and I was able to go to next waterfall step. But I'm facing another issue here.
Next prompt is not getting displayed but I can see it in Log 
This is how it shows in Emulator

[Emulator View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wftl.png)

Once user clicks the button control lands in `MoreInfoAsync` method

```
 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MoreInfoAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
            var goback = JObject.Parse(stepContext.Result.ToString());
            stepContext.Values["AdaptiveCardDetails"] = stepContext.Result.ToString();

            if (goback.ContainsKey("goBack"))
            {
                return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId);
            }
            // stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 2;

            else
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync("MoreInfo", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Tell Me more.") }, cancellationToken);
 }
```

I would like to go to initial dialog so I'm using `ReplaceDialogAsync`.

`MoreInfo` dialog is  not displayed in emulator but its shown in log

**Edit 3**: Here is the complete code of waterfall steps

```
          // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
                        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
                        {
                            ChoiceAsync,
                            CardAsync,
                            MoreInfoAsync,
                            ConfirmAsync
                        };
                        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
                        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("ChoiceType"));
                        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("AdaptiveCardPrompt"));
                        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("MoreInfo"));
                        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                options = new PromptOptions()
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Select the Choice"),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That was not a valid choice."),
                    Choices = GetChoices(),
                    Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
                };
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync("ChoiceType", options, cancellationToken);
            }


            private  async Task<DialogTurnResult> CardAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {

                var cardAttachment = new Attachment();
                stepContext.Values["leaveType"] = stepContext.Result.ToString();
                cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync("AdaptiveCardPrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                     Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
                     {
                         ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                         Content = cardAttachment.Content,
                     }),
                }, cancellationToken);
            }

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MoreInfoAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var goback = JObject.Parse(stepContext.Result.ToString());
                stepContext.Values["AdaptiveCardDetails"] = stepContext.Result.ToString();

                if (goback.ContainsKey("goBack"))
                {
                    return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId);
                }
                else return await stepContext.PromptAsync("MoreInfo", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Tell Me more.") }, cancellationToken);
            }

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                stepContext.Values["MoreInfo"] = stepContext.Result;
                //As of now I wouldn't perform any task here so I'll end
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
```

Comment: If the card is being displayed again, this likely has more to do with how you have your dialog set up, than how the card is sent. Can you include the code for your dialog? To go back, in the "catch result" step, you'd just need to see if `stepContext.Result` has your `go back` value (whatever value you set the card to send when clicking back)

Comment: Using `ReplaceDialogAsync` is a good idea and you're using it correctly. Tough to say why it isn't being shows. Can you either paste all of your code for the `MoreInfo` dialog or a link to your repo? Can you also describe your new issue a little more? Is it just that the dialog isn't restarting?

Comment: I have pasted complete code of `MoreInfo` dialog if you see emulator snapshot after submitting the  submit button the control goes to  `MoreInfo`  but in `Moreinfo` the prompt that im trying to return is not getting displayed in the emulator output screen. But I can see "Tell me more" in emulator log.Why isn't the same getting displayed to user on output. Where have I made a mistake

Comment: It's difficult to tell. `MoreInfoAsync` looks fine, so the problem is likely elsewhere. Do you have something like `AddDialog(new TextPrompt("MoreInfo"));`? If you can link to all of your code it would make this much easier to debug.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this. The problem might be with `await dialogContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(postbackActivity);` in `Run()`. Try deleting that, since you don't really need to send that. I've uploaded my code [to a github repo](https://github.com/mdrichardson/deleteMeLater) so you can take a look and try to find differences. Again, this would be significantly easier to debug with all of your code.

Comment: Thank a lot @mdrichardson its working fine now. Commenting `await dialogContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(postbackActivity);` just worked. But I didn't understand how it was creating a problem.

Comment: Tough to say without really digging through your code. My guess is that there's something in `OnTurnAsync` or `OnMessageAsync` that's throwing off how it decides to continue the dialog.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Could you please explain in brief what was affecting before when we used dialog extension class and how do we call dialog 's now.

Comment: Dialog Extension has been rolled into the SDK. I don't recall which version, but if you update to the latest, you should be able to just call [`Dialog.RunAsync...`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Bots/DialogBot.cs#L48). Just be sure to [Dependency Inject the dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Startup.cs#L44). There's a little more to it than that. Look at Core Bot sample. If you run into trouble, open a SO ? with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dealing with the Re-Prompt

The issue is with your `OnTurnAsync()` method:

```cs
 if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
 {
      await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
 }
```

Every time a user sends a message, it causes a new instance of your dialog to be run. Since Adaptive Card Input gets sent as a PostBack message (which is still a message), it causes the Dialog to run again, re-prompting the user.

If you're going to run dialogs from `OnTurnAsync()` or `OnMessageAsync()`, there's a couple of different things you should do, either:

1. Use if/switch statements. For example, if the message contains "help", run the HelpDialog, or
2. Start a dialog that saves user responses and skips steps as necessary. You can see an example of this in [Core Bot's Booking Dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/BookingDialog.cs). Notice how it's saving the user response in each step with something like `bookingDetails.TravelDate = (string)stepContext.Result;` and checks to see if it exists in the previous step before prompting with something like `if (bookingDetails.TravelDate == null)`. For yours, you might store something like `userProfile.AdaptiveCardDetails` or something.

#### Back Button

To get the back button working, let's say it looks like this in your Adaptive Card:

```
{
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Back",
    "data": {
        "goBack": "true",
    }
},
```

When the user clicks "Back", the bot will receive an activity with:

[image]

Since the user wants to go back and you don't need the data, you could do something like:

```cs
var activity = turnContext.Activity;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value.GetType().GetProperty("goBack"))
{
    dc.Context.Activity.Text = "Back";
}
```

and then in your Dialog step:

```cs
if (stepContext.Result == "Back")
{
    stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 2;
}
```