# Is it possible to set an adaptive card with date input in a waterfall dialog?(Using Bot Framework on Web and Teams)

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

Is it possible to set an adaptive card with date input in a waterfall dialog?(Using Bot Framework on Web and Teams).

What I need is user to select a date using adaptive cards Input.Date feature(Which is working everywhere except in Waterfall Dialogues) ie I need this adaptive card(which is already created as json in a local path) and return as context.PromptAsync() to next waterfall step.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible.

you can design **date-input** card schema on https://adaptivecards.io/designer. 

for more example using adaptive card [csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only not flagging this as a duplicate due to the date-input part. K. Ch's answer is correct, although partial.

For retrieving input from Adaptive Cards in Waterfall Dialogs, [see any of the previous times I've answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10860086+adaptive)

Specifically, [handle submit actions in Waterfall Dialogs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061325/how-to-retrieve-adaptive-cards-form-submission-in-subsequent-waterfall-step/55066910#55066910)

---

#### Other Resources

- [Official Botframework blog post on Adaptive Cards](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/)
- [AdaptiveCardPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5396). Auto-handles the Submit action and does a lot of other useful stuff. *Might* be integrated into the Botframework SDK someday. If you like it, show your support with a thumbs-up in that issue. You can still use the class, yourself, too.
- [Search Kyle Delaney's Adaptive Card answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2122672+adaptive). He handles a lot of Adaptive Card questions, too.
- [Adaptive Cards Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/) - In Preview/Alpha, but allows you to create cards a little more dynamically within the card's JSON.