# How to resume waterfall chatbot after click on card's submit button?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

i'been keep searching about how to resume waterfall step after click on on submit button in a adaptive card. is there any good idea to achieve this ? basically system has to wait till user click on adaptive cards submit button, and then move to waterfall's next step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve user entered input in adaptive card to the c# code and how to call next intent on submit button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251221/how-to-retrieve-user-entered-input-in-adaptive-card-to-the-c-sharp-code-and-how)

Comment: [See here for additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611984/is-it-possible-to-set-an-adaptive-card-with-date-input-in-a-waterfall-dialogus/58629750#58629750). I've [answered too many Adaptive Card questions to count. Just search them and you'll get every answer you could want](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a10860086%20adaptive)