# How to get data from adaptive card and send response based on it?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have created one waterfall dialog with two steps. When I click on the card, it displays the data as message from user. How to capture this data without being sent as message from the user and then sendActivity in step 2 based on the data.

My card 1 data:

```
        "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "TITLE",
        "data": "DATA"
    }
```

Waterfall steps-

```
async Step1(stepContext) {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity({
        attachments: [
            this.createAdaptiveCard1(),
            this.createAdaptiveCard2(),
            this.createAdaptiveCard3()


        ],
        attachmentLayout: AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel
    });
     return await stepContext.prompt('somePrompt','Choose an option');

    
}
async Step2(stepContext) {
//capture data value and do something
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve Adaptive Card's form submission in subsequent waterfall step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061325/how-to-retrieve-adaptive-cards-form-submission-in-subsequent-waterfall-step)